# Create table based on two nested foreach loops in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, foreach, html-table

I tried to create a week view table by using two nested foreach loop,
Model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public ServiceProvider Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DayViewModel> Days { get; set; }

}

public class DayViewModel
{
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
    public TimePeriodCollection FreeTimes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Blocks { get; set; }
}
```

So I have a list of dayes and each days has a list of times

In the view:

```
@model BookingSystem.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel
:
 <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Days)
            {
                <th class="text-center">
                    @item.TheDate.ToString("dddd") <br /> @item.TheDate.ToString("MM-dd")
                </th>
            }
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Days)
                {


                    <td class="text-center col-sm-15">
                        @if (item.FreeTimes != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var iu in item.FreeTimes)
                            {
                                <span>

                                    @Html.ActionLink(iu.Start.ToString("HH:mm") + " - " + iu.End.ToString("HH:mm"), "Index", "ClientForm", new { ChoosedStartTime = iu.Start.ToString("HH:mm"), ChoosedEndTime = iu.End.ToString("HH:mm"), ChoosedDate = item.TheDate }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                                </span>
                                <br />
                            }
                        }
                    </td>

                }

            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

I had an acceptable result but what I want is: each time block to be in a separate row so I can use table-striped class and put borders.
This is what I did:
[Image of the result](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1556904751193211&set=pb.100006211023889.-2207520000.1423664171.&type=3&theater)
Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick Solution would be to control by a variable.

Let's say you have Treatments and Appointments for a given Patient. It would be something like

```cs
    public class Patient: Person
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Treatment>? Treatments { get; set; }
    }
```

And a Patient as multiple Treatments

```cs
    public class Treatment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Treatment Type")]
        public TreatmentType TreatmentType { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Upfront Cost (INR)")]
        public decimal? UpFrontCost { get; set; } = 0;
        [DisplayName("Total Cost (INR)")]
        public decimal? TotalCost { get; set; } = 0;
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment>? Appointments { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public virtual Patient? Patient { get; set; }

    }
```

And each treatment would have multiple Appointments.

```cs
    public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Appointment Time")]
        public DateTime AppointmentTime { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Appointment Status")]
        public AppointmentStatus AppointmentStatus { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Charge (INR)")]
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; } = 0;
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Treatment))]
        [DisplayName(nameof(Treatment))]
        public virtual int TreatmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Treatment? Treatment { get; set; }

    }
```

Use this approach to have nested models rendered using @foreach in razor views.

```
<div class="row flex-row">
    <h4> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Treatments)</h4>
    <hr />
    @if (Model.Treatments.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>
            Treatment not started. <a asp-controller="Treatments" asp-action="Create" asp-route-patientId="@Model.Id">Start treatment</a> for this paitent!
        </p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table table-striped">
            @{
                var trHead = 0;
                var apHead = 0;
            }
            @foreach (var tmnt in Model.Treatments)
            {
                if (trHead == 0)
                {
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => tmnt.TreatmentType)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => tmnt.TotalCost)
                            </th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    trHead += 1;
                }
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(a => tmnt.TreatmentType)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(a => tmnt.TotalCost)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="float-end" asp-controller="Treatments" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@tmnt.Id">View treatment</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        apHead = 0;
                    }

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            @if (tmnt.Appointments.Count == 0)
                            {
                                <p>
                                    No Appointments Scheduled. <a asp-controller="Appointments" asp-action="Create" asp-route-treatmentId="@tmnt.Id">Schedule an appointment</a> for this paitent!
                                </p>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <table class="table mb-0">
                                    @foreach (var apt in tmnt.Appointments)
                                    {
                                        if (apHead == 0)
                                        {
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => apt.AppointmentTime)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => apt.AppointmentStatus)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => apt.Cost)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            apHead += 1;
                                        }
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => apt.AppointmentTime)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => apt.AppointmentStatus)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => apt.Cost)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="float-end" asp-controller="Appointments" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@apt.Id">View Appointment</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    }
                                </table>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Then, obtain the following output
[image]
[image]
Responsive mobile view (scope for some improvement though! :p

[image]

PS: using Bootstrap 5.1

References: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#nesting